# WebBrowser throwing unhandled exception

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, exception, browser

I'm trying to write a small program to log me in to my school's network at startup. Everything worked fine until recently when my web browser started throwing unhandled exceptions. This is my code:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("url")

While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
    Application.DoEvents()
End While
```

The error is thrown at the while loop, stating that

> Visual Studio cannot access a removed object

I noticed that this exception is not thrown if the opacity of the form is set to 100%. Any opacity setting under 100% causes the exception. However, setting opacity to 100% causes a lot of other errors in the program for some reason.

**What is causing this?** The WebBrowser is not touched at all during runtime except for navigation like this and I certainly did not remove it.

Comment: What is the purpose of the While loop?

Comment: To wait for the browser to complete its navigation before running the rest of the code.

Comment: You did not accurately quote the error message.  My best guess is that this is actually an ObjectDisposedException.  The kind of exception that's indeed *very* common when you use DoEvents().  Don't use DoEvents, use the DocumentCompleted event instead.

Comment: I translated from Swedish to English which is why I could not quote it directly, Hans. I use DoEvents for comfort as I use it a lot in my code, but that is not the problem. The problem arises at the start of the While loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.DoEvents()` causes all sorts of problems. You should not be using it.

My initial instinct was to remove the `While` loop altogether, as it does not appear to serve any purpose. But you said you had included it "to wait for the browser to complete its navigation before running the rest of the code." In that case, you should still take it out, but you should replace it with a handler for the [`WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx), which is raised when the WebBrowser control finishes loading a document. Place whatever code you want to run in that event handler method.

```
Private Sub YourCurrentMethod()
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("url")

    ' (no While loop)
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    ' your code goes here
End Sub
```

Comment: I have used this but found that I needed to wait very often in my code as it navigates around during log in, which is why I incorporated DoEvents in the first place. I execute a lot of different code at different times in my program, and this approach is simply not completely satisfying.

Comment: Events are exactly how you accomplish that, @Viktor. What part wasn't satisfying?

Comment: Say I need to navigate to one place, enter text/send, navigate to another, enter text/send and lastly navigate to a last page. How do I add this to a single event handler?

Comment: That is not really something you do in a Windows application, @Viktor. But if you have to, you'll need to set a class-level variable to keep track of where you are. Check that inside of each event handler to see what code needs to run. `DoEvents` will get you into lots of trouble. It looks like the easy solution, but it's not. You'd basically need to rewrite the entire event system that the .NET Framework provides for you.

Comment: OK. I will try to use the DocumentCompleted event for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

you should take care in the downloadcompleted event that it fire's more than once so to make sure that you actually have all the page loaded check the url that comes with this event like this

```
private _url as string = "some_url"
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    If e.Url.ToString <> _url Then Exit Sub
    ' your code goes here
End Sub
```